# How can I reduce the number of false positive variables when using LASSO?

Tags: multiple-regression, feature-selection, lasso, regularization

Given an n by p data matrix with n << p, it is known that when LASSO is applied on this matrix, it tends to over-select variables. How can I reduce the number of falsely selected variables?

Comment: What do you want to do with the model? If you want to do forecasting, I think overselection should not be a problem, because lasso delivers just the right balance between underselection and overselection when it comes to forecasting. If you want to build an explanatory model instead, you can use adaptive lasso. It is supposed to consistently select the true variables, but at the cost of poorer forecasting performance. (You cannot have a model that is optimal for both forecasting and for selecting the true variables at once. These are conflicting goals.)

Comment: @RichardHardy Do you mean that variable selection and forecasting are fundamentally opposed, or specifically in the case of lasso? Either way, I'd be interested to fimd out more. Could you recommend a reference?

Comment: Yes, I mean that. This is in general, not only for lasso. See Yang ["Can the strengths of AIC and BIC be shared? A conflict between model indentification and regression estimation "](https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article/92/4/937/389439/Can-the-strengths-of-AIC-and-BIC-be-shared-A) (2005).

Comment: See recent work by Tibshirani, Candes, and others at Stanford on the False Discovery Rate: https://www.google.com/search?q=fdr+lasso+tibshirani.  Both recently gave beautiful lectures on this topic at the JSM.

Comment: @RichardHardy As you mentioned, my goal is to build an explanatory model instead of forecasting. In practice, I have an impression that adaptive lasso is not so much different from lasso. Even if adaptive lasso reduces the number of falsely selected variables, I find the improvement not significant over lasso. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @whuber is probably referring to [this talk](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ftp/jsm2017.pdf). See e.g. slide number 17.

Comment: @Richard Thank you.  Actually, I did not see that one and it doesn't seem to cover the ideas I recall, such as Candes' idea of "knockoffs": https://www.google.com/search?q=candes+fdr+knockoff.  The ASA plans to make slides of all talks (subject to permission from the presenters) available online to ASA members in September.